# How can I repeat each song in a playlist n times?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, music, music-player, media-player

I have a playlist with 3 songs: a.mp3, b.mp3 and c.mp3. I want to have it play as follows. When I play the playlist, a.mp3 plays for 4 times. Then it goes to b.mp3 and plays it for 4 times. Lastly, it goes to c.mp3 and plays it for 4 times. When it finishes, it goes to start and play the cycle again.

Is there a way to do this, either by setting up the stock player appropriately, or by installing some third-party app which supports repeat counts?

Comment: This looks like a very, very custom (or specific) player request. I don't think there's anything like that yet. Nevertheless, app recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I know, but I have a little hope, yet... (sorry about off-topic, but I didn't find other forums/Q&A sites for this question, if you know somewhere, please guide me.)

Comment: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions

Answer (score 1):

You may have found this answer or another one by now but a simple way to achieve this (as long as you don't want to use the shuffle function) is to manually create a playlist and add each song multiple times.

Example (.m3u playlist in same directory as music):

```
#EXTM3U
a.mp3
a.mp3
a.mp3
a.mp3
b.mp3
b.mp3
b.mp3
b.mp3
c.mp3
c.mp3
c.mp3
c.mp3
```